# How to get the latest date with same ID in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to Get the Record with the most recent date as same ID's have different dates. Need to pick the BOLD values. Below is the sample data, As original data consist of 10000 records.

- ID  Date
- **5   25/02/2014**
- 5 7/02/2014
- 5 6/12/2013
- 5 25/11/2013
- 5 4/11/2013
- **3   5/05/2013**
- 3 19/02/2013
- 3 12/11/2012
- **1   7/03/2013**
- **2   24/09/2012**
- 2 7/09/2012
- **4   6/12/2013**
- 4 19/04/2013
- 4 31/03/2013
- 4 26/08/2012

Comment: @pnuts Yes Sorting is permitted and that second ID 1 is typing mistake sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is in column B use this formula and fill down
=LEFT(A1,1)

in column C
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,2,99))

then filter column B to a specific value of interest and sort by column C to order these values by date.

Edit: Even easier do a two level sort by B then by C newest to oldest.  The first B in the list is newest.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a programmatic / formula only solution or can you use a workflow? If a workflow will work, then how about this:

1. Construct a pivot table of your data
2. Make the Rows Labels the ID
3. Make the Values Max of Date

The resulting table is your answer.

```
Row Labels  Max of Date
1   07/03/13
2   24/09/12
3   05/05/13
4   06/12/13
5   25/02/14
```